# Create a javascript regex to find numbers starting with a # (but not including HTML special characters or existing links)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create links from certain strings. I've tried this:

```
([^&]#)([0-9]+)(?![^<>]*>)
```

But it's not working quite correctly.

```
Test 1: &#106
Test 2: #1040
Test 3: some text followed by #1060
Test 4: <a href="#1060">#1060</a>
Test 5: <b>#1078</b> (...or any other tag except <a>)
```

- Test `1` & `4`: **should NOT match**.
- Test `2`, `3` & `5`: **should match**.

I.e. It should match for a `#number` in any tag except for a link tag (nor it's attributes).

Here's a jsfiddle where you can test it out: `http://jsfiddle.net/xqnjs2uq/3/`

The regex in question is labelled "regex3" I've included two other regex's in there because their part of the bigger picture – just to be able to check whether this regex interferes with any of those.

**UPDATE**
With help from @chsdk I've managed to find a way to do this with two regex's (see regex3 and regex4 in the following jsfiddle)...

```
http://jsfiddle.net/xqnjs2uq/6/

/[^&|href="]+(#[0-9]+\b)/gim  --> matches Test 3 and 5 above
/^(#[0-9]+)/   --> required to match Test 2 above
```

1st prize would be for condensing this into a single regex. Is that possible?

Comment: Maybe [`(^#|[^&]#)([0-9]+)(?![^<>]*[<>])`](https://regex101.com/r/gC2hT2/1)?

Comment: That seems to work on http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/javascript/index.html but fails in my real-world tests for Test 2. Weird?

Comment: It is weird, I guess you should update the question with how you perform your real-life tests.

Comment: Tx. I've updated. Test 2 is passing but actually my real world test was not an example of Test 2 but rather of the newly added Test 5.

Comment: Perhaps, [`(^#|[^&\n]#)([0-9]+)(?![^<>\n]*(?:<\/a>|[^>\n]*>[^<\n]*<\/a>))`](https://regex101.com/r/gC2hT2/2) then?

Comment: @geoidesic simply use `/[^&|href="](#[0-9]+)/g`, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the following regex `/[^&|href="](#[0-9]+)/g`.

This is **[a live DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gD9nR0/2)**, giving those results:

[image]

With the following matches:

[image]

**EDIT:**

I missed the part where you want to avoid matching this expression within links, this is the regex you will need for this:

```
[^&|"](#[0-9]+\b)(?!<\/a>)
```

We added the `\b` here to make sure it takes the whole expression at a word boundary and `(?!<\/a>)` to avoid matching links.

And this is **[the Live DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gD9nR0/4)** again, and you can test it in the following Snippet:

```js
var re = /[^&|"](#[0-9]+\b)(?!<\/a>)/g;
var str = 'Test 1: &#106\nTest 2: #1040\nTest 3: some text followed by #1060\nTest 4: <a href="#1060">#1060</a>\nTest 5: <b>#1078</b> (...or any other tag except <a>)';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
    re.lastIndex++;
  }
  document.write("<b>" + m[1] + "</b><br/>");
}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. It's eating closing brace of tags. E.g. <p<a href="#/app/job/1078/1" target="_blank">#1078</a></p>. Note the broken p tag. This is after using replace on <p>#1078</p> using that regex.

Comment: This fiddle is broken, but just use the code in my snippet to replace it,

Comment: I have: http://jsfiddle.net/7acfut1r/1/ ... but it still doesn't work. Please notice how the <p> tag has become <p   (without the closing brace).

Comment: @geoidesic Yes I see, the problem is that the regex is matching the sequence group but capturing the previous character too, so the solution is to use `regex3.exec()` method like this `match = regex3.exec(string)[1]` and then use `match` variable in your replace, [this is the **updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/7acfut1r/2/), I hope it helps.

Comment: Thx @chsdk. Seems to work for some strings but not others. I've updated the jsfiddle with all the tests: http://jsfiddle.net/xqnjs2uq/5/.

Comment: @geoidesic Sorry, but I can't figure out the problem and what's causing it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `(^(#|(<[b-zB-Z]+>))((0-9)+)(?!(<\/*a>*)))`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution ^^. Hope this help you

```
/#[0-9]+/gi
```